# BoxLayout: Compilation Errors

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, boxlayout

I'm trying to make a BoxLayout layout in my program. I use Eclipse, so when I entered these lines,

```
JTextArea fntxt = new JTextArea(1, 20);
JTextArea lntxt = new JTextArea(1, 20);
JButton back4 = new JButton("Back");
JButton sub2 = new JButton("Submit");
JLabel cal = new JLabel("Create new Account");
JPanel cac = new JPanel();
//Error line:
cac.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cac, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

//In Constructor
    cal.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    cac.add(cal);
    cac.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
    cac.add(fntxt);
    cac.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
    cac.add(lntxt);
    cac.add(back4);
    cac.add(sub2);
```

it showed these errors in the error line:

```
- Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
- Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
 MethodHeaderName
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
- Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
 QualifiedName
```

and when I try to run it, this comes up in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at Create.main(Create.java:125)
```

The 125 line is the main method declaration line.
I can't understand what is the error and what to do to debug it.

Comment: You certainly have more information on the problems view.  Windows > Show view > Problems (Alt+Shift+Q X)

Comment: You don't have the "Error line" below your "In Constructor" comment, so I assume it is right inside the class declaration. In that case you need to enclose it with a block of curly braces `{ ... }`, i.e. put it into the instance initializer - or move it to the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra closing bracket, also this line has to be inside a method or constructor:

**inside constructor**

```
cac.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cac, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)));
                                     remove this------^
```

Comment: If that's really the problem (which it looks like) then a hint at the OP: Eclipse should mark that single extra bracket - so look for those the next time and count the opening bracketc.

Comment: I did change it but other problems still persist

Comment: @ApoorvaAditya, you must move this line `cac.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cac, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)));` inside contructor